# The product $\sigma$-algebra $\bigotimes _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathfrak{B}$ contains the sets of all bounded, monotone and convergent real sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, borel-sets, product-space

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Consider the product space $(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N},\bigotimes_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathfrak{B})$ with $\mathfrak{B}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\bigotimes _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathfrak{B}$ contains the sets of all bounded, monotone and convergent real sequences.

I could show that $\bigotimes _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathfrak{B}$ contains the set of all bounded sequences by considering the sets $\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:-\alpha<a_n<\alpha\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$.

For monotone and convergent sequences however I can only think of uncountable ways to define the sets. Can someone give me a hint on how to solve the rest?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: a convergent sequence (to a finite limit) is the same thing as a Cauchy sequence, so you don't have to worry about the number of possible limits being uncountable. Also, in the definition of Cauchy sequences you can take only rational values of $\epsilon>0$. So that way you will get only a countable number of intersections and unions.